# Avoid directory for some HTML files when permalink setting is pretty in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I've "permalink: pretty" in the config and this works pretty well with what I want with my static site (not a blog) - pages with "index.html" inside the folders/pages.

What is the best way to have a specific page or pages such as "error.html" render as "error.html" in my root folder and not "error/index.html"?

P.S. I want to use the default template so I can maintain the site design flow.

EDIT:

So far, here is the working method.

In the S3's "Enable Web Hosting" pane > Error Document have it as "error/index.html". This does work and is fine but I do wish to be able to control how some html's are rendered by Jekyll.

Comment: I assume you are working with GitHub pages?

Comment: I'm deploying to S3 and served with Cloudfront.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `permalink: pretty` in `_config.yml`, have a 404.md in your jekyll site root path, and want to have a "domain.com/404.html", simply add `permalink:` in the `.md` file:

```
---
layout: page
title: "404: Page Not Found"
permalink: 404.html
---
```

The 404.html will be in your `_site` root path.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the permalink format for each page individually in the YAML Front Matter.

However, Jekyll does not handle 404 errors at all. If you are GitHub pages, what your question indicates, then the 404.html file in the root folder will be served when an 404 error is encountered. The custom 404 **MUST NOT** be a Jekyll processed page but rather plain HTML. This means you can not specify YAML Front Matter. So basically, when you use GitHub Pages, GitHub will always serve your custom 404 file under the URL that you tried to reach. Period.

If you are hosting your Jekyll page yourself, then you should refer to your web servers manual.

Comment: I think we're getting closer. I'm hosted on S3 and served by Cloudfront. How do I do it there? Cloudfront just ask me the "error document".

Comment: So you are building locally and only pushing the already built site?

Comment: Yes, pushing just the content of _site.

Comment: Then you can have the error document be processed by Jekyll, set the permalink to "error/index.html" and it will be served by S3.

Answer (score -2):

Use 'permalink: none' in your _config.yml file, then it will not create error/index.html after build.

Comment: I'm sorry but you didn't seem to read my question. I like the "permalink: pretty". That works. I just want one single HTML not to follow that.